# How to define return type based on the parameters in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am creating a function which return `boolean` if the parameter is `true`, and return `boolean | undefined` if the parameter is `false`. I tried using `conditional types` or `overloaded functions`, but both not working, could anyone help out? Thank you!

```js
// first try using conditional type
const getData = <T extends boolean>(mandantory: T): T extends true ? boolean : (boolean | undefined) => {
    return mandantory ? false : undefined // Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T extends true ? boolean : boolean | undefined'.(2322)
}

// second try using overload functions
type GetData ={
    (mandantory: true):boolean;
    (mandantory: false): boolean | undefined
}

const getData1:GetData = (mandantory: boolean) => { // Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.(2322)
    return mandantory ? false: undefined
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=1#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgOYFM4BECGdMILwIA8AKgigB5wpQAmMCARhBADYqZQB8AFALYc0OcCACcAngC4ExAJRTSFKrXpwRAVxQIA-I2ZsOCKdyat2UBAB8Ea2igBmASygoaM-JwQBvUAl8IRaGoi5vy0QqJi2gh2mCwwmlI2NPZOLggA9Ol+xGIADpoA5EkpzjQFCA70UBCImDAwDkhQmAxsCMLteYUKlNR07eqaOib65lIjZpbWto6lBQB03ABMAMxLSzKgAL6guyBwXQgA4mhYOPjeIH4IfALh4lKqGnITHADcPn63YVDCD9GxeJyXSmAxWYqzFzbPaQWCIVAYbCYACMEhOiPOBG+gl+EXGejMbjwHk8GSy1xy+QQRRmqTKFSqNQQdQaTRabQ6BypBVeUAWyzWG0+vgCcCCITuuPEURicRQiVppWhICAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it with `function` syntax like this:

```typescript
function getData(mandatory: true): false;
function getData(mandatory: false): boolean | undefined;
function getData(mandatory: boolean): boolean | undefined {
    if (mandatory) {
        return false;
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

Writing it with a type and an arrow function, I couldn't get it to work without applying the type via a type assertion rather than just by typing the `const`:

```typescript
interface GetData {
    (mandatory: true): false;
    (mandatory: false): boolean | undefined;
}

const getData = ((mandatory: boolean): boolean | undefined => {
    if (mandatory) {
        return false;
    }
    return undefined;
}) as GetData;
```

[Both examples on the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQCIEMpYBQC2WYAJjnAE4CeAXIlBSKgJR3BYA2AzqgNwCwAKFCRYCFOmy5CxMlEq1E7bizoAjOHA6piiAD6JwJVMBhhUJAcPDR4SNJhz4ipctXWbtxVog1adSAZGJmYWiADeQojRiDDAiDKu8tTMEVExGRToIBRIyjxWGQC+6dFZUDlIwabmlkIlgkJmUKgU7BCoiADikk5pghmJcgp0DEw++XylCS7D7kqcPD5+XoGGpCG1Vg1CEAhcUBKOuABMiAC8CUNuiisBy54B+uvGNWHnAHz9GXEzsjepSIDDIxcqVBYqQoxBqZbK5F6bCzbVJYLjdXq4Ky7faHLAARguRyk+DGLF4MQA9BTEPjYmjJtiwAdfATLg5iXhJsxyYgqSy6b5Hroghs3iQhIzmVgzmyMdK8KTudE+dKBQzBHsmYc1DKiU4TpzFmTedSdQK7sKEWKhEA)

Comment: It is true. Overloadings are less strict than type intersections.

Comment: @captain-yossarian - Thanks! I wondered if that was the case.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAIDitwBECG53wLyngfAGTwAUpAtugHYAmN4A9gE6QBc84zArrAJS4AfPABm6ADYBnfvkIlyVOgxbtRE6QJzDudWCICW1WLT6yC8yjXrUmrDgCNGjcbBqbhYqQgA+8HbT1DY1MwEABjRmpJcHgAcxQMLABGNmQ0TGwcMkVrW1VHZ1dqd3gc5VZ4AH41L3gOf0CjWlBQIA

Thats why overloadings are a bit unsafe and acts similar like type casting

Comment: @captain-yossarian - Oh, I get it, I just figured there was a different way to deal with it rather than a type assertion (or `function` syntax). But if there isn't, there isn't. :-)

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder, I forgot the standard way to define overloading functions, using too much arrow function. Also finally proofed arrow function cannot do anything :)

Comment: @Ron - :-) Well, in this case you can use an arrow function if you want, it's just you need that type assertion. I'd call this one of the few cases where a type assertion is probably okay. Happy coding!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah, but with type assertion, we lost the type safety when writing this function, didn't we?

Comment: @Ron - Only partially. TypeScript won't let you do just any `x as Y`. I don't know the full details (I'm still relatively new at TypeScript), but it requires some level of compatibility between `x` and `Y`. Otherwise, you have to do `x as any as Y` or `x as unknown as Y`. [Here's an example](https://tsplay.dev/WyvQKw) where it wouldn't let you do the above. As captain-yossarian said above, TypeScript relaxes its usual rules for `function` overloads. (I don't know if that's the same relaxation or just similar.)

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder. I summarised the three ways I knew to solve the issue in this [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYhCGwCuAnCAVc0C8UDOwKAlgHYDmAsAFDWiRQDiEwAsvCQCaID2KIciVBADKwQXii4AFADMEyNJkgAuWPKFKIAGigBbdl2C8QqwkggBKSQD4oAI27cANghIBuWlkbMA8mGBE3CTwTgIKImLIEtJygopYqmEaWDr6nDx8qjIheJY29o4u7FAAPlBInBAypBAcHjRUdNBMwEloouKS3qwGGfzq7ZFIEmUtfgFBIW0R4vXU1ADGQQRQZMzTHVGqLRtD0VCyAxgJanHHkKm9RpkFzq5W2LYA3tRQb1BoCiR6V8ZQAPxQbJOXJQVQVDhVGocagAX3mVCWJBW8GUDjuxVwa1aR02wykAHJ4HYFgSdGZLAikSs7F1sbtxITITIyUCcpSqEA)